# "Signing and Capabilities" tab missing in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have been working on an Xcode 13.3.1 project, testing my code using a simulator.  When I was ready to test the app on my device, I navigated to the project settings and noticed that the "Signing and Capabilities" tab was no longer displayed as shown below.

[image]

So, I created a new app and the "Signing and Capabilities" tab ***is*** present in that app, as shown below.

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: In your first screenshot, did you select the project or an app target? What you are seeing in the first screenshot is expected behavior if you select the project. You have to select an app target to see a Signing & Capabilities tab.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal - thank you for your comment.  I have replaced the first picture that shows that you are correct, I have selected the project as the target.  Question: how do I select the app as the target.  Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges.

In the first screenshot you are editing the *project*. A project has no signing and capabilities.

In the second screenshot you are editing the *target*.

The editor interface is completely different because a project and a target are different things.

Comment: so as an Xcode newby, the $1,000,000 question is: how do I switch to editing the target.   So, I guess this is really the substance of this post.  It may be super-obvious to experienced XCoders, but not to me.  Thanks!

Comment: In the first screenshot do you see the up and down arrows next to Virtual Tourist 2 in the second line? That means this is a menu. Click it.

Comment: Or click the icon to the left of Virtual Tourist 2 in the second line to reveal the navigation interface that you have hidden.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the answer I was looking for.  The answer is super-simple for experienced Xcoders, but for newbies, not so much.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Signing and Capabilities tab was not available because you had the project selected in the Project Editor instead of an app target. Select an app target, and you will see the Signing and Capabilities tab.[image]

In your comment you mentioned not being able to select the app target. For some reason the target list was hidden for you in the project editor. Click the button the arrow is pointing to in my screenshot to show the target list and select the app target.